# BitBlt captures only partial screen

Tags: c++, windows, gdi, bitblt

I am trying to capture a square part of the screen using GDI under Windows 10. This is how I tried:

```
//Get screen DC
desktop = GetDC(NULL);

//Create a compatible bitmap of 32 x 32 px.
HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(desktop);
HBITMAP captureBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hCaptureDC, 32, 32);
SelectObject(hCaptureDC, captureBmp);

//loop:
BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, 32, 32, desktop, sourceX, sourceY, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(desktop, 0, 0, 32, 32, hCaptureDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

So I capture a 32x32 px rectangle at `(sourceX, sourceY)` into the bitmap and draw it onto the screen (top left corner).

However, this results in mostly black squares. Only things that have been drawn by GDI before get captured. I am quite sure that the first `BitBlt` is the problem. If I specify `WHITENESS` as the last parameter, I get a white square, which is what I would expect. So the capturing from screen to the bitmap seems to be problematic.

If I copy directly from screen to screen using

```
BitBlt(desktop, 0, 0, 32, 32, desktop, sourceX, sourceY, SRCCOPY);
```

, everything works as expected.

I also tried the flag `CAPTUREBLT`.

How can I capture the entire region into the bitmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
HBITMAP captureBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hCaptureDC, 32, 32);
```

Should be

```
HBITMAP captureBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(desktop, 32, 32);
```

The reason is explained on the [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183488(v=vs.85).aspx) for `CreateCompatibleBitmap` :

> When a memory device context is created, it initially has a 1-by-1 monochrome bitmap selected into it. If this memory device context is used in CreateCompatibleBitmap, the bitmap that is created is a monochrome bitmap. To create a color bitmap, use the HDC that was used to create the memory device context